# How to upload 60x60 tab bar icon in IOS

Tags: objective-c, tabs, icons, uitabbar

I'm using XCode 6.1 and have uploaded 30x30 icons for my tab bar icons. But of course I should be able to upload 60x60 for higher res ones, right? But for the life of me I can't figure out where the option for that is in the upper right corner of the editor. I only see the option to choose one image. Can anyone help me?
Thank you in advance,
Brent

Answer (score 0):

First of all you really need to include up to 3x images now for iPhone 6 plus

Add your images for your tab bar icons to your project eg: 
`tabBarIcon.png`, (30x30)
`tabBarIcon@2x.png`, (60x60)
`tabbarIcon@3.png` (90x90)

Then in XCode editor select `tabBarIcon.png` and at runtime the correct image size will be selected for the device you're targeting